# How to access a variable from the model in view (Yii framework)?

Tags: php, yii

Have a model:

```
public static function newMessagesCount() {
    $count = 0;
    $currentUser = Yii::app()->user->id;
    // Build criteria where user have a new messages
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->condition = 'to_id = :to_id AND is_read = :is_read';
    $criteria->params = array(':to_id' => $currentUser, ':is_read' => 0);

    //Count items
    if (Message::model()->exists($criteria)) {
        $count = Message::model()->count($criteria);
    }
    return $count; }
```

I need to access in the form of $count. So for example like this:

```
<li class="btn btn-primary white"><i class="icon-download"></i><?php echo CHtml::link('Inbox', array('message/inbox')); ?></li><?Message::newMessagesCount()?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not outputting the function result.
Use `echo Message::newMessagesCount()` in your view.